# Cant populate list collection when selected from ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

The `Combobox` pulls the Names Column from the SQL database however when selected I need the other properties from the `dentist` list to be populated in the labelled `TextBoxes`.

On the `If` statement is where I get the error and the highlighted code is `dent.Name`. The error is as follows:

> Description:   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

```
namespace DentistSurgery
{
    public partial class Dentist_Info : Form
    {
        Surgery mySurgery = new Surgery();
        public SqlCommand SelectCommand;
        private SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataRow dr;
        Surgery _formsSurgery;        

        public Dentist_Info(Surgery SurgeryToDisplay)
        {    
            _formsSurgery = SurgeryToDisplay;                
        }

        public void FillCombo()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GGJG; Initial Catalog = DentistDB; Integrated Security = True"))
            {
                SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DentistInfo", conn);
                conn.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
                da.Fill(ds);

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["DentistName"].ToString());
                }
                //conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public Dentist_Info()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillCombo();        
        }

        public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Dentist> dentistList = new List<Dentist>();
            Dentist dent = new Dentist();

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex = dent.Name)
            {
                txtDName.Text = dent.Name.ToString();
                txtDSurname.Text = dent.Surname;
                txtDDOB.Text = dent.DOB.ToString();
                txtGender.Text = dent.Gender;
                txtSalary.Text = dent.Salary.ToString(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of your code. Just post the code like you did with the rest of the code.

Comment: Sorry I will refrain from doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedIndex` property is of type `int` and you want to compare it with a string value. You need to use `ToString()` method to convert it to string also you should use the equality operator `==` instead of assignment operator  `=` in your `if` statement like this:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() == dent.Name)
{
    ....
```

But based on `dent.Name` I think you should use `SelectedItem` property here but again because the `SelectedItem` is of type `object` you should use `ToString()`:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == dent.Name)
{
   ...
```

Comment: Yes it did resolve my initial error however I now have an issue as the strings I'm trying to populate into the text boxes are empty due to me creating a new instance of the Dentist and dentistlist. 

I understand that this is a separate issue so would I need to close this one and start another. 

Or could you answer how I could instantiate the dentist or dentistlist without creating a new instance of it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the equality operator (==). You are using the assignment operator (=). Hence why you get the error...

`"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' DentistSurgery"`

Because you're trying to assign the selected index (which is of type int) to a string.

This means you should be using `comboBox1.SelectedValue` (which is of type string). Then you can use the equality operator (==) to compare the values like so...

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == dent.Name)
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`dent` is new, empty object. `dent.Name` gives empty `string` and you cannot put implicitly convert `string` to `integer` which is `SelectedIndex`.

**edit**: 
because of other problems (and additional questions), here is  a bit more code.

So, your `dentistList` is empty, and `dentist` is also empty. In that case, comparing dentist with selected item is useless.
Try to rearrange your code like this. I also added some comments:

```
//I'm assuming this is form 
public partial class Dentist_Info : Form
{
    //create list of dentists here, so that it is visible thru whole form.
    private List<Dentist> dentistList = new List<Dentist>();

    public Dentist_Info(Surgery SurgeryToDisplay)
    {

        _formsSurgery = SurgeryToDisplay;


    }

    public void FillComboAndListOfDentists()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GGJG; Initial Catalog = DentistDB; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DentistInfo", conn);
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["DentistName"].ToString());

                // creating new dentist
                Dentist dent = new Dentist();
                dent.Name = dr["DentistName"].ToString();
                dent.Surname = dr["DentistSurname"].ToString();
                //etc...

                //add dentist to list
                dentistList.Add(dent);
            }
            //conn.Close();
        }
    }


    public Dentist_Info()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        FillComboAndListOfDentists();        

    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //use LINQ to find specific dentist in the list (btw, you should use something unique, some kind of ID, not just Name
        Dentist dent = dentistList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == comboBox1.SelectedValue);

        // once you have your dentist, fill all the details...
       if (dent != null)
       {
            txtDName.Text = dent.Name.ToString();
            txtDSurname.Text = dent.Surname;
            txtDDOB.Text = dent.DOB.ToString();
            txtGender.Text = dent.Gender;
            txtSalary.Text = dent.Salary.ToString();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Reply, I didn't know that SelectIndex was of type int.

However I have now been able to get rid of the error with coverting to string however you have made another point in which the string I'm trying to populate is empty as it is new.

How would I get around this, how would I instantiate the list without stating it as new or even the dentist

Comment: that if statement is useless. First of all, your list of dentists should be filled with data (you can easily move `dentistList` declaration out of `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method, put it in class and fill it with same data you're using to fill combo . Then you can select specific dentist from that list using name from combobox (like this: `var dentist =  dentistList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == comboBox1.SelectedValue);` Then, variable `dentist` will contain the data needed to display in texboxes.

Comment: The Dentist is in a surgery class and I called the Dentist so that I could call the stores in the dentistlist which is in the Surgery class.

Comment: I have edited my answer using your code. check it out.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this Nino...

I already have a dentistList which I load in the Surgery class(I don't know how to load the code from my Surgery Class otherwise I would attach it) I connect to the database and read the info which then stores the columns in the List<>.

Could I not use this list<> in my Dentist form

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to get the `selected Value` from the `comboBox` using `comboBox1.SelectedValue` and then compare it to dentName.

```
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Dentist> dentistList = new List<Dentist>();
        Dentist dent = new Dentist();


       if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == dent.Name)
        {
            txtDName.Text = dent.Name.ToString();
            txtDSurname.Text = dent.Surname;
            txtDDOB.Text = dent.DOB.ToString();
            txtGender.Text = dent.Gender;
            txtSalary.Text = dent.Salary.ToString();

        }


    }
```

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedValue **==** dent.Name)